# Hash Map in Python

Tags: python, hashmap

I want to implement a HashMap in Python.  I want to ask a user for an input. depending on his input I am retrieving some information from the HashMap. If the user enters a key of the HashMap,  I would like to retrieve the corresponding value.

How do I implement this functionality in Python?

```
HashMap<String,String> streetno=new HashMap<String,String>();
   streetno.put("1", "Sachin Tendulkar");
   streetno.put("2", "Dravid");
   streetno.put("3","Sehwag");
   streetno.put("4","Laxman");
   streetno.put("5","Kohli")
```

Answer (score 365, accepted):

[Python dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is a built-in type that supports key-value pairs. It's the nearest builtin data structure relative to Java's HashMap.

You can declare a dict with key-value pairs set to values:

```
streetno = {
    "1": "Sachin Tendulkar",
    "2": "Dravid",
    "3": "Sehwag",
    "4": "Laxman",
    "5": "Kohli"
}
```

You can also set a key-value mapping after creation:

```
streetno = {}
streetno["1"] = "Sachin Tendulkar"
print(streetno["1"]) # => "Sachin Tendulkar"
```

Another way to create a dictionary is with the `dict()` builtin function, but this only works when your keys are valid identifiers:

```
streetno = dict(one="Sachin Tendulkar", two="Dravid")
print(streetno["one"]) # => "Sachin Tendulkar"
```

Comment: The second example just builds a dict in the same ways as before and then copies it. The other use `dict`, which would be more appopriate in this context, is `dict(key1=value1, key2=value2, ...)` but that requires the keys to strings which are also valid Python identifiers (and internally, this also creates a dictionary).

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't realize that naked strings were valid identifiers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly (what are "naked strings"?), but I believe you got it backwards. Your updated second example is invalid and I never intended to state something like that work. The [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) syntax, which accepts *only* naked identifiers, internally uses a dictionary. The `dict` constructor supports keyword arguments and works like `def dict(**kwds): return kwds` if given keyword arguments.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a "map" and it acts like a "map". But the question is not "Map in Python" but "Hash Map in Python": Are dictionaries a hash(!) map?

Comment: @user2661619 Yes. The underlying implementation of a dict uses a hash function to generate the address location of the item. The implementation is here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/10eea15880db/Objects/dictobject.c

Comment: Why don't you just tell me dictionary is hashmap

Comment: @Dwa probably because it's not.

Answer (score 40):

All you wanted (at the time the question was originally asked) was a hint. Here's a hint: In Python, you can use [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 33):

It's built-in for Python. See [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Based on your example:

```
streetno = {"1": "Sachine Tendulkar",
            "2": "Dravid",
            "3": "Sehwag",
            "4": "Laxman",
            "5": "Kohli" }
```

You could then access it like so:

```
sachine = streetno["1"]
```

Also worth mentioning: it can use any non-mutable data type as a key. That is, it can use a tuple, boolean, or string as a key.

Answer (score 22):

Hash maps are built-in in Python, they're called [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
streetno = {}                        #create a dictionary called streetno
streetno["1"] = "Sachin Tendulkar"   #assign value to key "1"
```

Usage:

```
"1" in streetno                      #check if key "1" is in streetno
streetno["1"]                        #get the value from key "1"
```

See the documentation for more information, e.g. built-in methods and so on. They're great, and very common in Python programs (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 19):

```
streetno = { 1 : "Sachin Tendulkar",
            2 : "Dravid",
            3 : "Sehwag",
            4 : "Laxman",
            5 : "Kohli" }
```

And to retrieve values:

```
name = streetno.get(3, "default value")
```

Or

```
name = streetno[3]
```

That's using number as keys, put quotes around the numbers to use strings as keys.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the implementation of the Hash Map using python
For the simplicity hash map is of a fixed size 16.
This can be changed easily.
Rehashing is out of scope of this code.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = [None for _ in range(16)]
    def get(self, key):
        index = hash(key) & 15
        if self.store[index] is None:
            return None
        n = self.store[index]
        while True:
            if n.key == key:
                return n.value
            else:
                if n.next:
                    n = n.next
                else:
                    return None
    def put(self, key, value):
        nd = Node(key, value)
        index = hash(key) & 15
        n = self.store[index]
        if n is None:
            self.store[index] = nd
        else:
            if n.key == key:
                n.value = value
            else:
                while n.next:
                    if n.key == key:
                        n.value = value
                        return
                    else:
                        n = n.next
                n.next = nd

hm = HashMap()
hm.put("1", "sachin")
hm.put("2", "sehwag")
hm.put("3", "ganguly")
hm.put("4", "srinath")
hm.put("5", "kumble")
hm.put("6", "dhoni")
hm.put("7", "kohli")
hm.put("8", "pandya")
hm.put("9", "rohit")
hm.put("10", "dhawan")
hm.put("11", "shastri")
hm.put("12", "manjarekar")
hm.put("13", "gupta")
hm.put("14", "agarkar")
hm.put("15", "nehra")
hm.put("16", "gawaskar")
hm.put("17", "vengsarkar")
print(hm.get("1"))
print(hm.get("2"))
print(hm.get("3"))
print(hm.get("4"))
print(hm.get("5"))
print(hm.get("6"))
print(hm.get("7"))
print(hm.get("8"))
print(hm.get("9"))
print(hm.get("10"))
print(hm.get("11"))
print(hm.get("12"))
print(hm.get("13"))
print(hm.get("14"))
print(hm.get("15"))
print(hm.get("16"))
print(hm.get("17"))
```

Output:

```
sachin
sehwag
ganguly
srinath
kumble
dhoni
kohli
pandya
rohit
dhawan
shastri
manjarekar
gupta
agarkar
nehra
gawaskar
vengsarkar
```

Comment: I think your logic is partially correct! `hash(key) & 15`, `73%15= 13`, but it's equivalent: `1001001 & 0001111 = 0001111` i.e `9` and not `13`, I think using mod is the correct operation. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: How do you iterate through the list though?

Answer (score 11):

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 64
        self.map = [None] * self.size

    def _get_hash(self, key):
        hash = 0

        for char in str(key):
            hash += ord(char)
        return hash % self.size

    def add(self, key, value):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        key_value = [key, value]

        if self.map[key_hash] is None:
            self.map[key_hash] = list([key_value])
            return True
        else:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
                if pair[0] == key:
                    pair[1] = value
                    return True
                else:
                    self.map[key_hash].append(list([key_value]))
                    return True

    def get(self, key):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        if self.map[key_hash] is not None:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]: 
                if pair[0] == key:
                    return pair[1]
        return None

    def delete(self, key):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)

        if self.map[key_hash] is None :
            return False
        for i in range(0, len(self.map[key_hash])):
            if self.map[key_hash][i][0] == key:
                self.map[key_hash].pop(i)
                return True

    def print(self):

        print('---Phonebook---')
        for item in self.map:
            if item is not None:
                print(str(item))

h = HashMap()
```

Answer (score 9):

Python [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is also a good option in this case:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(["Sachin Tendulkar", "Sachin Tendulkar", "other things"])

print(counter)
```

This returns a dict with the count of each element in the list:

```
Counter({'Sachin Tendulkar': 2, 'other things': 1})
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question. What you get here is a dictionary where names are keys and values are some counters (where did you get the input list from anyway?). While the question was looking for a hash map where unique keys point to names as values.

Answer (score 7):

In python you would use a dictionary.

It is a very important type in python and often used.

You can create one easily by

```py
name = {}
```

Dictionaries have many methods:

```py
# add entries:
>>> name['first'] = 'John'
>>> name['second'] = 'Doe'
>>> name
{'first': 'John', 'second': 'Doe'}

# you can store all objects and datatypes as value in a dictionary
# as key you can use all objects and datatypes that are hashable
>>> name['list'] = ['list', 'inside', 'dict']
>>> name[1] = 1
>>> name
{'first': 'John', 'second': 'Doe', 1: 1, 'list': ['list', 'inside', 'dict']}
```

You can not influence the order of a dict.

Answer (score 4):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python is the best way to implement this. We can create the following dictionary using the given `<key,value>` pairs:

```py
d = {"1": "Sachin Tendulkar", "2": "Dravid", "3": "Sehwag", "4": "Laxman", "5": "Kohli"}
```

To extract the value of a particular key, we can directly use `d[key]`:

```py
name = d["1"] # The value of name would be "Sachin Tendulkar" here
```

Answer (score 1):

That is my solution for LeetCode problem [706](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-hashmap/):

A hash map class with three methods: `get`, `put` and `remove`

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class MyHashMap:

    def __init__(self, size=100):
        self.items = [None] * size
        self.size = size

    def _get_index(self, key):
        return hash(key) & self.size-1

    def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        index = self._get_index(key)
        item = self.items[index]
        if item is None:
            self.items[index] = Item(key, value)
        else:
            if item.key == key:
                item.value = value

            else:
                while True:
                    if item.key == key:
                        item.value = value
                        return
                    else:
                        if not item.next:
                            item.next = Item(key, value)
                            return
                        item = item.next



    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        index = self._get_index(key)
            
        if self.items[index] is None:
            return -1
        item = self.items[index]
        while True:
            if item.key == key:
                return item.value
            else:
                if item.next:
                    item = item.next
                else:
                    return -1
        
        

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        value = self.get(key)
        if value > -1:
            index = self._get_index(key)
            item = self.items[index]
            if item.key == key:
                self.items[index] = item.next if item.next else None
                return
                
            while True:
                if item.next and item.next.key == key:
                    item.next = item.next.next
                    return
                else:
                    if item.next:
                        item = item.next
                    else:
                        return
```