# Is there more effective way to get result (O(n+m) rather than O(n*m))?

Tags: python, loops

`Origin data` as below show, every item has a type mark, such as `interests, family, behaviors, etc` and I want to group by this type field.

```py
return_data = [
{
      "id": "112",
      "name": "name_112",
      "type": "interests",
    },
    {
      "id": "113",
      "name": "name_113",
      "type": "interests",
    },
      {
      "id": "114",
      "name": "name_114",
      "type": "interests",
    },
      {
      "id": "115",
      "name": "name_115",
      "type": "behaviors",
    },
         {
      "id": "116",
      "name": "name_116",
      "type": "family",
    },
         {
      "id": "117",
      "name": "name_117",
      "type": "interests",
    },
    ...
]
```

And `expected ouput` data format like:

```py
output_data = [

    {"interests":[
        {
          "id": "112",
          "name": "name_112"
        },
        {
          "id": "113",
          "name": "name_113"
        },
        ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "behaviors": [
            {
                "id": "115",
                "name": "name_115"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "family": [
            {
                "id": "116",
                "name": "name_116"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

And here is my trial:

```
type_list = []
for item in return_data:
    if item['type'] not in type_list:
        type_list.append(item['type'])

interests_list = []
for type in type_list:
    temp_list = []
    for item in return_data:
        if item['type'] == type:
            temp_list.append({"id": item['id'], "name": item['name']})
    interests_list.append({type: temp_list})
```

Obviously my trial is low efficient as it is O(n*m), but I cannot find the more effective way to solve the problem.

Is there more effective way to get the result?  any commentary is great welcome, thanks.

Comment: In your output data, why have multiple single-key dictionaries instead of just one dictionary?

Comment: thanks for your replying,  it's just a data format making deal with front-end

Comment: In that case, I'll delete my answer. Seems inefficient though...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen anyway thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` to store a list of items for each type:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# group by type
temp_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in return_data:
    temp_dict[item["type"]].append({"id": item["id"], "name": item["name"]})

# convert back into a list with the desired format
output_data = [{k: v} for k, v in temp_dict.items()]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        'behaviors': [
            {'name': 'name_115', 'id': '115'}
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'family': [
            {'name': 'name_116', 'id': '116'}
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'interests': [
            {'name': 'name_112', 'id': '112'},
            {'name': 'name_113', 'id': '113'},
            {'name': 'name_114', 'id': '114'},
            {'name': 'name_117', 'id': '117'}
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

---

If you don't want to import `defaultdict`, you could use a vanilla dictionary with `setdefault`:

```
# temp_dict = {}

temp_dict.setdefault(item["type"], []).append(...)
```

Behaves in exactly the same way, if a little less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

please see [Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703509/11266491) for map.

```
for item in return_data:
typeMap[item['type']] = typeMap[item['type']]  + delimiter + item['name']
```